# Problem related to Wilson's theorem in number Theory

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Wilson's Theorem state that, If $n$ is a prime number, then $\dfrac{(n-1)!}{n}\equiv-1\pmod n$.

In other words,

$\dfrac{(n-1)!}{n}$ is a non-integer if $n$ is a prime number.

I am struggling, if we delete any one of the integers from the expansion of $(n-1)!$ still the fraction $\dfrac{(n-1)!}{n}$ is a non-integer number?

Comment: Wilson's theorem states $$(n-1)!\equiv -1\mod n$$ if and only if $n$ is prime for $n\ge 2$ , without denominator $n$. That $\frac{(n-1)!}{n}$ is not an integer if $n$ is prime is clear since $n$ would have to divide one of the positive integers $1,\cdots ,n-1$ which is not the case. Removing integers out of the product in the numerator does not change this, the fraction remains a non-integer.

Comment: I got you, it's very helpful@Peter. Thank you!